# Google Map not working when in a second tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I am setting up a demo site and I am using a plugin to embed a google map on my site. The map has a marker which pins the event location. It is in the second tab on this page: https://funnelmechanics.com/mixagogo-v2/event/demo-event-2

The problem is when I click on the location tab, the map does not show. Please can someone help me with the code I need to fix this?

I know if I open the tab and refresh it will work, but is there a way to refresh make the map work without refreshing the page?

The technology used is WordPress, VisualComposer and ToolSet.

All help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
John

Comment: Google map does not like to be hidden. You can trigger "render map" on second tab appears.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: I am not sure how to help as you are using wordpress with third-party plugin. You have to either edit the plugin by yourself or find another one that works.

Answer (score 0):

you need to refresh the page when opening the tab. Send a refresh event to the page when accessing the tab.

If you open the tab and then manually refresh the browser, you will see your map!

try adding `location.reload();` when the tab is opened

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there a way to fix this without having to refresh the browser?

Comment: Since you are using WordPress plugins, I am not sure how to edit it and force the page to reload. But try to either search in the puggin how to force an event when the page is opened or embed your JS code to do so. maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530121/refresh-currently-open-tab-with-javascript-when-a-new-tab-is-opened